# Passing asp-route-data to a page handler using jquery ajax unobtrusive

Tags: razor, razor-pages

I want to pass asp-route-data to a page handler in a page model in razor pages using jquery ajax unobtrusive. How do I modify the following code so that my page handler

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public IActionResult OnGetPartial(int? data)
    {
        return new PartialViewResult { 
            //return a partial page and update #panel
        };
    }
}
```

receives an argument named data

```
@page
@model IndexModel
<div id="panel"></div>
<a href="" asp-route-data="20" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-url="/index/partial" data-ajax-update="#panel">Click here</a>
<div id="panel"></div>
```

In the above razor markup, I have tried adding asp-route-data to the  element but it doesn't pass the value to the page handler

Comment: I want to use jquery ajax unobtrusive to pass asp-route-data  to a page handler named `OnGetPartial(int?  data) {} `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add a route template to the page so that the handler is found:

```
@page "{handler?}"
```

Then pass the route data as a query string value e.g:

```
data-ajax-url="/index/partial?data=20"
```

If you want to set the value from JavaScript, you can do so like this (using jQuery):

```
$('a[data-ajax-update="#panel"]').first().data('ajax-url', '/index/partial?data=' + your_value);
```